# Answer tab show "sorry no answers" for short time

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Go to a question with non zero answers. Tap on answers tab. Notice orange no answer button is visible, until answers load. Was expecting progress spinner instead. Happens more with slow network conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The correct behavior (showing a loading indicator) was already the case here but a related bug fix from last month broke it and I didn't notice that, sorry about that. It's been fixed for the next update, 0.1.51 coming out later tonight.